# Can't update nodejs in 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04, updates, dependencies, nodejs

I got this message when trying to update nodejs and nodejs-dev (with `--with-new-pkgs` option) in Ubuntu 18.04.

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev but 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.1 is going to be installed
              Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
 libssl1.0-dev : Conflicts: libssl-dev but 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4.1 is going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408425/trying-to-install-debian-package-npm-makes-apt-get-to-remove-libssl-dev

Answer (score 1):

Use n module from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

To upgrade to latest version (and not current stable) version, you can use

```
sudo n latest
```

To undo:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs-legacy     # fix /usr/bin/node
sudo n rm 6.0.0     # replace number with version of Node that was installed
sudo npm uninstall -g n
```

Comment: Make sure you've opened a new terminal window before `node -v`